# DOS window in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux

Is there any way to open an MS-DOS window in Linux Mint 19.1, that is similar to Windows?

I know how to run terminal. I want to run a DOS window such that I can run a DOS based lisp application. Ideally, I want to have several DOS windows open at one time, and I want to be able to resize them as needed

Comment: What do you mean with "DOS window"? A terminal window? A DOS emulation? How do you open this window? What exactly does not work when you want to resize the window or how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I know how to run terminal.  I want to run a DOS window such that I can run a DOS based lisp application.  Ideally, I want to have several DOS windows open at one time, and I want to be able to resize them as needed.

Comment: You can run DOS programs via Wine, see https://www.winehq.org

Comment: Yes but the functionality is split: For the terminal emulator, you can choose one of the many. Then for the DOS interpreter there is wine, or dosbox, or … You can launch these from `bash`.

Comment: I have removed bits of the question, that make is seem to be about terminal emulators.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I'm new to Linux Mint.  Can you tell me the command in bash to run the dos window?  Thanks.

Comment: some choices: wine, dosbox, dosemu, virtualbox. I have never done it. You can also try installing and using lisp (Which lisp are you trying to run?).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I'm using a very old version called MuLisp, from Soft Warehouse.  It is not ANSI Common Lisp, so the large amount of code that I have written over the years will not run on a new system without a lot of modification, which is why I am asking about DOS windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/)

Comment: I did look at DOSBox, and it didn't seem to do what I wanted.

Comment: @DavidWhite would you care to explain *why* it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: In DOSBox, I couldn't resize the DOS window, and I apparently couldn't open more than one DOS window at a time.  In WINE, I never could get it to open a DOS window.

Comment: Try this link: https://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/microsoft-ms-dos-early-source-code/ look for download, compile it and run it in qemu ;-)